# user sign-up fields on form not being saved to the database

Tags: ruby, forms, ruby-on-rails-4

I've bult a landing page where users can submit their email

I have the following database:

```
  create_table "subscriptions", force: true do |t|
    t.string   "fname"
    t.string   "lname"
    t.string   "email"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
  end
```

And the following form on my pages/home view:

```
                <div class="form-subscribe">
                    <%= form_for(@subscription, { :class => 'form-horizontal' }) do |f|  %>

                        <div class="form-inputs subscription-box">
                            <div class: "form-space">
                                <div class: "form-group">
                                    <%= f.text_field :fname, class: "form-control sub-field", placeholder: "First Name" %>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class: "form-space">
                                <div class: "form-group">
                                    <%= f.text_field :lname, class: "form-control sub-field", placeholder:"Last Name" %>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class: "form-space">
                                <div class: "form-group">
                                    <%= f.email_field :email, class: "form-control sub-field", placeholder:"Email" %>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-actions">
                          <%= f.button :submit, class: "btn btn-default"%>
                        </div>

                    <% end %>

                </div>
```

Whenever I try to fill out the form it seems like it works but then I visit the console and I see a new record being formed but all the fields are nil except the id field. Why is this happening?

Here is my subscritpions controller:

class SubscriptionsController < ApplicationController

```
def new
    @subscription = Subscription.new
end

def create
    @subscription = Subscription.new
    if @subscription.save
        redirect_to root_path
    end
end
```

end

Here is my pages controller:

```
class PagesController < ApplicationController

    def home
        @subscription = Subscription.new
    end

end
```

I'm pretty new at this so not sure what is going on here, any ideas?

Comment: Didn't you have set the `strong params` method set in your controller?

Comment: Hmmm I may have forgotten those, are those necessary? I'm reading about them now. Also which controller. I don't get why we have to have 2 controllers for this...

Comment: Did my answer worked for you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you are using **`Rails4`**,you have to use **`Strong Parameters`** to permit the required attributes.

Update your `SubscriptionsController` like this

```
class SubscriptionsController < ApplicationController

def new
    @subscription = Subscription.new
end

def create
    @subscription = Subscription.new(subscription_params)
    if @subscription.save
       redirect_to root_path
    else
    render 'new'
    end
end

private
def subscription_params
params.require(:subscription).permit(:fname,:lname,:email)
end
```

Have a look at **`Strong Parameters`** in these **[Guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#strong-parameters)**